# do I need to write different set of code for both the orientations of Mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m designing an appliaction for mobile phone. Do I need to write different set of code for both the orientations of mobile? Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Are you designing an application, or a mobile web site?

Comment: I m designing an application for add, view, update records like we develop for pc.

Comment: Then you really tagged your question incorrectly, which caused all the answers below to be for a mobile website. Tag it with android, iphone, or ios instead, and you'll get answers for native app development.

Comment: my problem is just interface view and not the execution part which is running perfectly on all the devices....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use media queries css to design both orientation and have a look on this url

[CSS-Tricks: Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Look on this URL  http://trentrichardson.com/2011/03/11/effective-example-of-css-media-queries/

Comment: This link is definetely going to help me. I just want to know whether I need to write different html code for both the orientations?

Comment: not necessary to write html code twice. But you have to add css in different mediaqueries use same classes but u need to change height, width, font-size etc according to the layout orientation.

Comment: when you minimizing the screen automatically sets the css in html page.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways if you are making you style sheet in pixels then you have to make separate style sheet but if you are using percentage then your style sheet works in both orientation

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a web application for pc, you need not to worry about the code related with application.All the code for pc version will be active for mobile too.But you need to worry about the page layout-for this you can build a separate mobile version or you can build a mobile compatible website by using separate stylesheet.

I will recommend you to build a separate mobile version page.But still you need not to modify the code related with application.

For mobile page, you can use [jquery mobile framework](http://jquerymobile.com)

Answer (score 0):

Good to see some ways you can refer [here!](http://designwoop.com/2012/03/15-detailed-responsive-web-design-tutorials/)